# WCF REST: passing a generic list as a request

Tags: xml, wcf, rest

I have a POST with a WebMessageFormat.Xml.  It's a simple method that takes in a Company object.  Aside from simple types containing "CompanyId", "CompanyName", "CompanyDescription etc., inside the XML there is a series of the same element containing tons of metadata involving contacts.  I wanted to pop that into a List.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.testcompany.com/2010/01")]
public class Company
{
     ...
     ...
     [DataMember] public List<CompanyContact> CompanyContacts;
}
```

The request goes through fine but the list is empty.  The other fields are populated from the request without issue.  Any ideas of what step I'm missing?

Here's a snapshot of my svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" 
                Debug="true" 
                Service="CompanyService"
                Factory="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost2Factory"%>
```

Using the "/help", I doubled checked the schema I'm passing in with the examples provided by the help page.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still reviewing the demo code I created but the issue was resolved.  I created a Contact class  for all the metadata in the XML.  I added a List to the Company object.  I wrote the XML and created a request through Fiddler.  Everything worked accordingly.

Now I'm going back to my original app to see if I can track why the collection is empty.  I need to review that the XML is correct and that my data contracts are proper.